# Can't run MS Access query through C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have this query in MS Access that runs excellent!

```
SELECT 
    BK_LEVEL9.Aitur AS Aitur, 
    Sum(BK_LEVEL9.M_NewQty) AS M_NewQty, 
    Sum(BK_LEVEL9.ErrorCount) AS ErrorCount, 
    (IIf([M_NewQty]<>0,Round(([ErrorCount]*100)/[M_NewQty],2),0)) AS ErrorProcc
FROM 
    BK_LEVEL9
GROUP BY 
    BK_LEVEL9.Aitur;
```

In my C# program I try to run this query like this:

```
SQL = "SELECT Aitur,M_NewQty,ErrorCount,ErrorProcc from MyQUERY";
dsWorkKabat = new DataSet();
adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Conn);
adp.Fill(dsWorkKabat, "MyQUERY");
adp.Dispose();
```

and I got this error:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'IIf(Not [M_NewQty]=0,Round([ErrorCount]*100/[M_NewQty],2),0)' as part of an aggregate function.

What could be the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that is exatly this query that works in Access? Because there is a strange orphan parentesis before IIf and I can't understand what is the result of this query (what you you want to do with IIf expression? Group? Sum? Avg?

Comment: in access that query run's excellent

Comment: If this runs fine inside Access itself then I would consider that the bug/problem/incorrect behavior. There is a reason every SQL based database requires all columns in the result to be part of the aggregate function or part of the grouping criteria and that is; which value should it pick if the rows that made the group contains different values? In this case, if two rows make a group, and they have M_NewQty 0 in one row and 10 in another, which value do you want to show?

Answer (score 1):

For almost every DBMS (MySQL is the only exception I'm aware of, but there could be others), every column in a SELECT that is not aggregated needs to be in the GROUP BY clause. In the case of your query you need to group it like that:

```
GROUP BY 
    BK_LEVEL9.Aitur, IIf([M_NewQty]<>0,Round(([ErrorCount]*100)/[M_NewQty],2),0);
```

Comment: This solution seems a shotgun debugging... Anyway, it does not produce the same result of the original query if Aitur is not a PK.

Answer (score 0):

Making some tests it seems that access computes the first three columns (the group by query) than computes ErrorProcc using the aliases.

Take care because the suggestion of israel altar does not work if BK_LEVEL9.Aitur is not a primary key (I'm quite sure is not otherwise the MyQuery query does not require a Group by clause).
Why doesn't it work:
Access computes the Group by before performing sums so the Group by of the IIf is based on the BK_LEVEL9.M_NewQty and BK_LEVEL9.ErrorCount and not on the aliases.

What is the solution? Probably the simplest is to delete the IIf from MyQuery than compute it in the ADO query.